# Place Zooming Image center in UIScrollView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I want to center the UIImageView and perform the Zoom on That. As per the below code the Zooming is work fine. But my UIImageView start from below NavigationBar. But I want to UIImageView center and also Zoom in center and enlarge the contentSize of UIScrollView in center.

**Code :**

```
scrollView = new UIScrollView();
scrollView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height - 20.0f);
View.AddSubview(scrollView);

dicom_image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Size.Width,300));
dicom_image.Image = dicomItem.uiimage;

dicom_image.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

if (dicomItem.uiimage != null)
{
    dicom_image.Image = ExtensionMethods.MaxResizeImage(dicomItem.uiimage, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width);
    dicom_image.ClipsToBounds = true;
    dicom_image.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    dicom_image.SizeToFit();
};
dicom_image.Center = scrollView.Center;


scrollView.ContentSize = scrollView.Frame.Size;
scrollView.AddSubview(dicom_image);

scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1f;
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return dicom_image; };
```

from the above code zooming is working fine but i want to UIImageView to be center.

**Edit :**

this code is work fine for Zoom but image start from beginning not the center.

```
scrollView = new UIScrollView();
                            scrollView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height - 20.0f);
                            View.AddSubview(scrollView);

                            dicom_image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Size.Width,300));
                            dicom_image.Image = dicomItem.uiimage;
                                        dicom_image.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;

                            dicom_image.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

                            if (dicomItem.uiimage != null)
                            {
                                dicom_image.Image = ExtensionMethods.MaxResizeImage(dicomItem.uiimage, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width);
                                dicom_image.ClipsToBounds = true;
                                dicom_image.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
                                dicom_image.SizeToFit();
                            };

                            dicom_image.Center = scrollView.Center;


                            scrollView.ContentSize = dicom_image.Frame.Size;
                            scrollView.AddSubview(dicom_image);

                scrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
                scrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;

                scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
                scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1f;
                scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return dicom_image; };

                UITapGestureRecognizer doubletap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(OnDoubleTap)
                {
                    NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 // double tap
                };
                scrollView.AddGestureRecognizer(doubletap);
```

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using constraints, you can set the bounds of the UIImageView.

This is a striped down example using a `CIFilter` to resize the image that I used for an Instagram viewer.

```
//someUIImageInstance is a CGImage-backed UIImage
var xScale = (float)(View.Frame.Size.Width / someUIImageInstance.CGImage.Width); 
var yScale = (float)(View.Frame.Size.Height / someUIImageInstance.CGImage.Height); 
var scale = Math.Max(xScale, yScale);
var lanczosScaleTransform = new CILanczosScaleTransform
{
    Image = someUIImageInstance.CGImage,
    Scale = scale
};
var yPosition = (scale * View.Frame.Size.Height) / 2;
imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Size.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height))
{
    Image = UIImage.FromImage(lanczosScaleTransform.OutputImage),
    Bounds = new CGRect(0, yPosition, View.Frame.Size.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height - yPosition),
    UserInteractionEnabled = true,
};
scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height))
{
    MinimumZoomScale = 1f,
    MaximumZoomScale = 3f,
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray
};
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView = (scrollView) => { return imageView; };

scrollView.AddSubview(imageView);
View.AddSubview(scrollView);
```

[image]

Note: It is easier if you use constraints in terms of centering the `UIImageView` and controlling the center of the viewport as the image is zoomed...

Comment: how i can set center Image using constraint if user zoom by the finger.

Comment: @Ironman you dynamically adjust them via the scrollview's delegate (`scrollViewDidZoom:`). As another note, using an `MTKView` to render the `CIImage` as a texture is lightening fast and that way you can chain the CIFilter(s) and the view directly to the GPU, scrolling/zomming is smooth as silk as you can render just the CIImage extent that is showing on the screen, i.e. no pixelization of the original image ;-)